# Monitor outgoing specific traffic

Tags: traffic, attacks

I have kinda of an idea but I want to consult. I was following this guide for finding out which php processes spawn outgoing brute force attacks. I found the culprits everything is working fine.

Now, how could I make an automatic system for all of this? Some kind of script that inserts the cron job, creates the other script, sets-up everything, finds the IP addresses with grep in the files and then analyzes the other files to give me the specific php process + domain.

Or maybe it would be simplier to have a script to check outgoing traffic for lets say matches as POST /xmlrpc.php.

Or maybe this has been solved all together and I am wasting time.

The specific guide: https://www.nocser.net/clients/index.php/knowledgebase/484/How-to-Detect-Website-Used-for-Hacking-Others.html

Thanks for any input :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have kinda of an idea but I want to consult. I was following this guide for finding out which php processes spawn outgoing brute force attacks. I found the culprits everything is working fine.

The problem is that your approach is *insane*.

You have no idea if the attackers left other backdoors, and you have not patched the vulnerability. The normal response to such security issues is *not* to find the one script with a problem - but rather restore from backup or code repositories.

That said, there's plenty of Intrusion Detection Systems out there. But the marked is usually for finding compromised machine, not script level - for reasons I outlined above.

Comment: This is for site hosting, and wordpress vulnerabilities appear every day, not much I can do to control them without impacting other users.